# Problem installing psycopg2 for Python venv through poetry

Tags: psycopg2, python-venv, python-poetry

I am installing psycopg2 into a python venv through poetry `poetry add psycopg2` but i get the below error.

I have tried to use older versions of psycopg2. Does anyone know why this problem occurs and how to properly fix it?

Following other questions on Stackoverflow I tried to install psycopg2-binary which is installed properly but later, that gives different issues when trying to apply django migrations.

> Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with psycopg2 (2.9.9) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --use-pep517 "psycopg2 (==2.9.9)"'.

Comment: It would be useful for future visitors if you included the actual error message from pip's output. The snippet that you have quoted does not tell us what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

Running the below on my machine solved the issue:

`apt install libpq-dev gcc`

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely caused by missing libraries needed to compile psycopg2. It is [recommended](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#quick-install) to use the pre-compiled binary through the wheel available at PyPI with `pip install psycopg2-binary`. This should be faster to install and is more likely to work than installing psycoog2 from source.